I cannot run python code with Code Runner
Whenever I try to run a python code in vs code (macOS) it does not run and gives me the following message: "zsh: command not found: python".
But if I disable the extension of Code Runner, the code runs. I need this extension for c++. How can I solve this?
I searched for different configurations on the extension settings, but I could not find anything to solve it.

if there's an option to change the command that the extension runs, try changing it to python3 followed by whatever the rest of the command is. Python on MACs is usually preinstalled as python3.
